# How to safely populate pg_notify payload?

Tags: postgresql, json, csv

Data makes its way into my application with prepared statements and stored procedures, so I'm not too worried about injection. When a new user signs up, I want to send an activation email. Presently I'm doing this with a trigger and a notification. It looks something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION on_sign_up() RETURNS trigger as $$
  DECLARE
  BEGIN
    PERFORM pg_notify('sign_ups', NEW.user_id || ',' || NEW.email || ',' || NEW.activation_code);
    RETURN new;
  END;
$$ language plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER on_sign_up_trigger AFTER INSERT ON user_account
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE on_sign_up();
```

My problem is the notification payload. If the email contains a comma, then I can't just split the string on ','. How do I escape anything and put it into the payload? I can add my own custom CSV escaping function and invoke it, but any time I think something like that is the right answer, I'm usually missing something.

It doesn't necessarily need to be CSV, I just thought that'd be the easiest.

*Note:* there are other solutions - e.g. strip the "prefix" and "suffix" and then treat the rest as the email. I'm more interested for this general class of sanitization/escaping from within PostgreSQL itself.

The table I'm trying to extract is as follows:

```
                  Table "user_account"
     Column      |  Type   |         Modifiers          
-----------------+---------+----------------------------
 user_id         | integer | not null
 email           | citext  | not null
 password_hash   | text    | not null
 activated       | boolean | not null default false
 activation_code | uuid    | default uuid_generate_v4()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than worrying about how to escape it. Just use JSON as a transport layer. Here we use [`row_to_json`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

```
CREATE FUNCTION on_sign_up() RETURNS trigger as $$
  DECLARE
  BEGIN
    PERFORM pg_notify('sign_ups', row_to_json(NEW)::text );
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Exactly what I came here to say. Use a json payload.

Comment: Life goal accomplished, do exactly what @CraigRinger does somewhere, with something pertaining to PostgreSQL.

Comment: This seems like an all around better strategy. Trying this now (I haven't looked around much), I got "cannot cast type user_account to json". Have I botched something? Or perhaps because I'm using UUID?

Comment: @user2152081 updated, my bad. Use `row_to_json`

Comment: Client 9.5.7 and server 9.6.2. 

SELECT 
  row_to_json(r)
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      *
    FROM user_account) r; 

works for me, so presumably it's in the right neighborhood.

Comment: @user2152081 mark the question as answered if you're satisfied with the answer.

Comment: @EvanCarroll - I appreciate your enthusiasm, but as written it is still not functioning for me so it seems like it'd be premature to accept it. Seeing this: "function pg_notify(unknown, json) does not exist", following https://stackoverflow.com/a/31757242/2152081 and changing it to "row_to_json(NEW)#>>'{}'" works for me. Does that seem right? If so, and you update your answer to reflect that I'll accept it.

Comment: Just cast `row_to_json(...)::text`

Comment: @CraigRinger - that works for me, and definitely looks tidier. Thanks for the tip - obviously I'm not so familiar with Postgres...

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: The maximum payload size that can be used for `pg_notify` is 8000 bytes. Source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-notify.html